# qt ios application crashes on text input focus

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, qt, qt4

I am working on qt ios application. I had a scenario were in i had to work with ios xib files which contains text boxes.I integrated xib files into qt-ios,and the display is good.
     The problem is when i focus on the displayed text box in qt-ios, the app crashes without any logs.
The same code works fine in native ios.
         Does qt-ios requires any permission to access keyboard from qt.Please help.